# Bash Script: unary operator expected error?

Tags: bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILETYPES=( "*.html" "*.css" "*.js" "*.xml" "*.json" )
DIRECTORIES=`pwd`
MIN_SIZE=1024

for currentdir in $DIRECTORIES
do
   for i in "${FILETYPES[@]}"
   do
      find $currentdir -iname "$i" -exec bash -c 'PLAINFILE={};GZIPPEDFILE={}.gz; \
         if [ -e $GZIPPEDFILE ]; \
         then if [ `stat --printf=%Y $PLAINFILE` -gt `stat --printf=%Y $GZIPPEDFILE` ]; \
                then    gzip -k -4 -f -c $PLAINFILE > $GZIPPEDFILE; \
                 fi; \
         elif [ `stat --printf=%s $PLAINFILE` -gt $MIN_SIZE ]; \
            then gzip -k -4 -c $PLAINFILE > $GZIPPEDFILE; \
         fi' \;
  done
done
```

This script compresses all web static files using `gzip`. When I try to run it, I get this error `bash: line 5: [: 93107: unary operator expected`. What is going wrong in this script?

Comment: `find "$currentdir"`, not `find $currentdir`. `"$(foo)" -gt "$MIN_SIZE"`, not `$(foo) -gt $MIN_SIZE` (and `$()` in place of backticks if you want saner nesting behavior). `"$PLAINFILE"`, not `$PLAINFILE`. And, yes, you need to export any variables you want subprocesses to see.

Comment: Backing up -- why not let `find` decide whether the file is larger than your minimum or not? There's no need to use a shell for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILETYPES=(html css js xml json)
DIRECTORIES=("$PWD")
MIN_SIZE=1024

IFS='|' eval 'FILTER="^.*[.](${FILETYPES[*]})\$"'

for DIR in "${DIRECTORIES[@]}"; do
    while IFS= read -ru 4 FILE; do
        GZ_FILE=$FILE.gz
        if [[ -e $GZ_FILE ]]; then
            [[ $GZ_FILE -ot "$FILE" ]] && gzip -k -4 -c "$FILE" > "$GZ_FILE"
        elif [[ $(exec stat -c '%s' "$FILE") -ge MIN_SIZE ]]; then
            gzip -k -4 -c "$FILE" > "$GZ_FILE"
        fi
    done 4< <(exec find "$DIR" -mindepth 1 -type f -regextype egrep -iregex "$FILTER")
done
```

- There's no need to use `pwd`. You can just have `$PWD`. And probably what you needed was an array variable as well.
- Instead of calling bash multiple times as an argument to `find` with static string commands, just read input from a `pipe` or better yet from a named `pipe` through process substitution.
- Instead of comparing stats, you can just use `-ot` or `-nt`.
- You don't need `-f` if you're writing the output through redirection (`>`) as that form of redirection overwrites the target by default.
- You can just call `find` against multiple files once by making a pattern as it's more efficient. You can check how I made the filter and used `-iregex`. Probably doing `\( -iname one_ext_pat -or -iname another_ext_pat \)` can also be applicable but it's more difficult.
- `exec` is optional to prevent unnecessary use of another process.
- Always prefer `[[ ]]` over `[ ]`.
- `4<` opens input with file descriptor `4` and `-u 4` makes `read` read from that file descriptor, not `stdin (0)`.
- What you probably need is `-ge MIN_SIZE` (greater than or equal) not `-gt`.

Come to think of it, `readarray` is a cleaner option if your bash is version 4.0 or newer:

```
for DIR in "${DIRECTORIES[@]}"; do
    readarray -t FILES < <(exec find "$DIR" -mindepth 1 -type f -regextype egrep -iregex "$FILTER")
    for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
        ...
    done
done
```

Comment: Might NUL-delimit output from the find on FD 4.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How's that possible?

Comment: If you mean about using `-d $'\0'` and `-print0`: I skipped the idea since it just makes things complicated. It's very rare for filenames to have newlines. Besides we already filter them.

Comment: I don't much buy "rare" as an excuse -- the last time I saw multiple TB of logs deleted by accident, it was triggered by a bug causing a buffer of random data to be used as a filename -- but already-filtered is a perfectly fine reason. Making that reason explicit has some advantage, though, inasmuch as folks learning from this answer can understand that it's something they'd need to do were that filtering not in place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Depends on the context.

Comment: ...as an aside, by the way -- I tend to consider `-d $'\0'` misleading, as it implies that NULs can be represented within C strings. `-d ''` is perhaps preferable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I actually kind of feel like I had trouble with both IFS and argument to `-d` unset but I'm lazy to try digging it again. At least for now I don't want to. I also don't see how that can be misleading as `read` doesn't really read strings but raw binary data. `-d ''` is actually more misleading since it doesn't tell how `read` would use and act with a delimiter.

Comment: `-d` always uses the first character of its argument. The empty string's first character is NUL, because bash uses C strings. `$'\0'` is **exactly the same** as `''` -- not just in the context of `read`, but *everywhere*. That's what I mean by misleading -- implying to the reader that the language has facilities (such as the ability to represent NUL bytes within strings) that it doesn't. One might make the individual snippet of code slightly clearer, but at the expense of sowing confusion about language capabilities as a whole.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok I read the source code and you are correct. Bash does C strings in most cases. Because of it `$'\0'` is meaningless and is just as good as `''`. And the problem I mentioned about `IFS` and `-d` having empty arguments was actually about trying to split a set of null-terminated strings with one instance of read through IFS which isn't possible due to the fact that Bash respects C string and ends up only reading one.

Comment: I do always get idea about this and may actually also had same conclusion of the behaviour a long time ago but I don't always practically remember. I always first respect the possibility of Bash storing some of the strings like vectors instead as of being null-terminated, than trying to check the behaviour again. And in most cases it's when I do `-d $'\0'`. I did refer to some of my latest posts that `-d ''` may be equivalent but didn't want to examine if it was really similar again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to export the `MIN_SIZE` variable. The bash you are having `find` spawn doesn't have a value for it so the script runs (as I just mentioned in my comment on @ooga's answer) `[ $result_from_stat -gt ]` which is an error and (when the result is `93107`) gets you `[ 93107 -gt ]` which (if you run that in your shell) gets you output of:

```
$ [ 93107 -gt ]
-bash: [: 93107: unary operator expected
```

Comment: The other thing is using quotes. `-gt "$MIN_SIZE"` would prevent missing data turning into a syntax error.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy With `-gt` that wouldn't actually help though. Because `[ 93107 -gt "" ]` is still a syntax error. (Which I'd argue is a good thing because silently comparing against zero instead of the expected value is a bad failure mode though apparently that is what `[[` does.)

Comment: It's an error, yes, but not a **syntax** error. Having the syntax be correct means a more informative message (about the empty string not being a number) is possible.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fair enough. The type of error does change. How much that helps figuring out the problem in this sort of case I'm not sure though. You still have to figure out that you are getting an empty variable expansion but perhaps it might be helpful to someone. None of this makes the `[[` behaviour make sense to me though.

Comment: "Integer expression expected" is, IMHO, vastly clearer than "unary operator expected", so my expectation is that the level of help is rather significant.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is clearer on what the failure was but it doesn't help you figure out why. Namely, in this case it wouldn't have pointed to an empty `MIN_SIZE` specifically, it could just has easily have been a file name problem in the stat call, or whatever. That was my point.

Comment: Knowing what the error is provides a pretty big start on figuring out the "why" oneself. If one doesn't understand string-splitting behavior, the original message is pretty darned opaque. Keep in mind that the OP's question wasn't "why is one of these two variables blank?", but "WTF does this error message mean?"

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My point is that being told that "integer expression expected" doesn't tell you that a variable is blank anymore than "unary operator expected" does. It does tell you that something went wrong with the test in a different way though. Do a search for both those errors and you find people equally confused. The fact that the volume differs is, I think, largely attributable to lack of quoting rigor and not comprehensibility of the error message.